# mySQL change cnf to remove NO_ZERO_IN_DATE

Tags: mysql

I need to import a SQL script here is the error I have :

```
Preparing...
Importing script.sql...
Finished executing script
ERROR 1292 (22007) at line 2093: Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'date_add' at row 1
Operation failed with exitcode 1
```

Here is what I have after `SELECT @@sql_mode;` :

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

I would like to remove the `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_DATE` that could probably fix my sql import error.

I can set the sql_mode to an **empty string** by writing in **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf** :

```
sql_mode = ""
```

but I can't set it to :

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

or the mysql server crashes.

Is there a way to only remove thoses parameters ?

Comment: What is result of SELECT @@VERSION; ?

Comment: I'm on 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3

Comment: If you have a /etc/mysql/my.cnf file, set sql_mode in this file, below the mysqld section

Comment: I did but it's either I remove everything or I write everything. I can't only remove ZERO related modes.

Comment: Check out this URL - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-the-use-of-ALLOW-INVALID-DATES-SQL-mode  it may help.